# How to join two count statements from two tables in SQLITE?

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, subquery, where-clause

I am working on dataset related to an application similar to Yelp and Tripadvisor.
I am running queries in SQL. I need to retrieve data from two different tables. I need the total count of Check-ins and total count of photos uploaded for each businesS. One table contains photo_id, business_id, label, and caption. Another able contains business_id, and date. I have written the query below but it does not retrieve the total count of check-ins and photos at the same time. Either results come up as NONE.

```
    SELECT b.name, b.stars, b.review_count
   ,(SELECT COUNT (ch.business_id) AS total_checkin
    FROM checkin ch
    WHERE (ch.business_id = b.id) 
    GROUP BY ch.business_id) AS total_checkin

   ,(SELECT COUNT (photo.id) AS total_photos
    FROM photo
    WHERE (photo.business_id = b.id) AND (label = 'food')
    GROUP BY business_id) AS total_photos
    
    FROM business b
```

Comment: `NONE` is not an SQL result. I guess you are executing this code through a Python app. So post the Python code because as it is your query should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, if the data structures are those you described. I would, however, suggest a few changes:

```
 SELECT b.name, b.stars, b.review_count,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM checkin c
        WHERE c.business_id = b.id
    ) AS total_checkin,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM photo p
        WHERE p.business_id = b.id AND p.label = 'food'
    ) AS total_photos
FROM business b
```

That is:

- no need for `GROUP BY` clauses in the subqueries: these are *scalar* subqueries, that always return one row (if there is no corresponding checkin on photo, you get a count of `0`)
- no need to alias the count inside the subquery (the alias is needed in the outer query only)
- use table aliases consistently
- parentheses around conditions in the `WHERE`  clause are superfluous